# Chaining & to_proc on symbol

Tags: ruby, symbols, proc

It's well known to Rubyist `&` will call `to_proc` on a symbol, so

```
[:a, :b, :c].map(&:to_s)
```

is equivalent to

```
[:a, :b, :c].map { |e| e.to_s } # => ["a", "b", "c"]
```

Say I want to call another method right after `to_s`, these two implementations will work:

```
[:a, :b, :c].map { |e| e.to_s.upcase }
[:a, :b, :c].map(&:to_s).map(&:upcase)
```

My question is, is there a way to chain the `&` `Symbol#to_proc` call in one parameter? Something like:

```
[:a, :b, :c].map(&:to_s:upcase)
```

Thanks!

Comment: No, there is no such way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're only doing:

```
%i[a b c].map { |e| e.to_s.upcase }
```

then just use the block and get on with more important things. If you're really doing a chain of Enumerable calls and find the blocks too visually noisy:

```
%i[a b c].map { |e| e.to_s.upcase }.some_chain_of_enumerable_calls...
```

then you could toss your logic into a lambda to help clean up the appearance:

```
to_s_upcase = lambda { |e| e.to_s.upcase }
%i[a b c].map(&to_s_upcase).some_chain_of_enumerable_calls...
```

or throw it in a method and say:

```
%i[a b c].map(&method(:to_s_upcase)).some_chain_of_enumerable_calls...
```

Either way, you're giving your little bit of logic a name (which is pretty much all `&:symbol` is doing for you) to make the code more readable and easier to understand. In the specific case of `to_s.upcase`, this is all a bit pointless but these approaches are quite useful when the block gets bigger.

Answer (score 5):

You will need to define some method in advance, but this will have generality. You can do like this:

```
class Symbol
  def * other
    ->x{x.send(self).send(other)}
  end
end

[:a, :b, :c].map(&:to_s * :upcase)
[:a, :b, :c].map(&:to_s * :capitalize)
...
```

I chose `*` as a method for functional composition.

And if you think you might use a third symbol, you can define like:

```
class Proc
  def * other
    ->x{call(x).send(other)}
  end
end
```

Comment: I like the idea but it feels too smart, too creative. If the `*` operator doesn't get very well known in your codebase, then 1 year from now you'll look at the `&:to_s * :upcase` line and will have no idea what it does nor how to find out what it does.

Comment: @Gaston I agree with the idea that it is not very explanatory but this part *"nor how to find out what it does"* is actually fairly simple. Since this is written in pure ruby (read not a C extension)  `:to_s.method(:*).source_location` and it will tell you the location of the source code for this method and thus you can determine what it does.

Comment: @engineersmnky wow! I didn't know about `.source_location`! Nice.

Answer (score 4):

So just for fun (and to prove that almost anything is possible in ruby if one puts in a bit of effort) we could define a method on `Symbol` (we'll call it `Symbol#chain`) to provide this functionality and a little more

```
class Symbol
  def proc_chain(*args)
    args.inject(self.to_proc) do |memo,meth|
      meth, *passable_args = [meth].flatten
      passable_block = passable_args.pop if passable_args.last.is_a?(Proc)
      Proc.new do |obj|
        memo.call(obj).__send__(meth,*passable_args,&passable_block)
      end
    end
  end
  alias_method :chain, :proc_chain
end
```

This can then be called like so

```
[:a, :b, :c].map(&:to_s.chain(:upcase))
#=> ["A","B","C"]
# Or with Arguments & blocks
[1,2,3,4,5].map(&:itself.chain([:to_s,2],:chars,[:map,->(e){ "#{e}!!!!"}]))
#=>  => [["1!!!!"], ["1!!!!", "0!!!!"], ["1!!!!", "1!!!!"],
#        ["1!!!!","0!!!!", "0!!!!"], ["1!!!!", "0!!!!", "1!!!!"]]
```

Can even be used as a standalone

```
p = :to_s.chain([:split,'.'])
p.call(123.45)
#=> ["123","45"]
# Or even 
[123.45,76.75].map(&p)
#=> => [["123", "45"], ["76", "75"]]
```

Comment: @JordanRunning I had not that's really cool although golfier than I might like

Comment: Oh, I don't think it's practically useful, but as a proof-of-concept it's amazing.

Answer (score 3):

While we're playing with syntax, how about monkey-patching Array with a `to_proc` method?

```
class Array
  def to_proc
    return :itself.to_proc if empty?
    ->(obj) { drop(1).to_proc.call(first.to_proc.call(obj)) }
  end
end

["foo", "bar", "baz"].map(&[:capitalize, :swapcase, :chars, ->a{ a.join("-") }])
# => ["f-O-O", "b-A-R", "b-A-Z"]
```

See it on repl.it: https://repl.it/JS4B/1

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to chain using the symbol to proc.

However, you could monkey patch a method to the class you are mapping over that will do both, then call that.

```
class Symbol
  def to_upcase_str
    self.to_s.upcase
  end
end

[:a, :b, :c].map(&:to_upcase_str)
```

Comment: You forgot to call `map` method for Array

Comment: How is this any better than using the block?  Why monkey patch `Symbol` just for one very specific scenario?

Comment: @Wand, Austio made no such claim. If answers only contained better ways of doing something we would all be the poorer.  As well, q&a's would be less entertaining.

Comment: @WandMaker, cary is correct just example of how he could accomplish what he was wanting.  Ruby allows different ways to approach problems and this answer could help someone else googling for the answer that do not understand this area of ruby well.  I would agree that just using a block would be better in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

I am surprised no body mentioned about `Proc#<<` and `Proc#>>`:

```rb
[:a, :b, :c].map(&(:to_s.to_proc << :upcase.to_proc))
# => ["A", "B", "C"]
[:a, :b, :c].map(&(:upcase.to_proc >> :to_s.to_proc))
# => ["A", "B", "C"]
```

ref: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Proc.html#method-i-3C-3C

Comment: No mentioned it because back in the dark ages of 2017 we were running 2.5 as the leading edge of Ruby. https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Proc.html but now yes this syntax will work although I would still prefer an elixir like operator ( `|>` ) for piping.