# How can I call two methods simultaneously using `&`

Tags: ruby

Instead of calling one method in a block using `&`,

```
objects_array.collect(&:errors)
```

can I call two methods simultaneously using `&`? I want something like this:

```
objects_array.collect(&:errors.full_messages)
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Note that the method calls you want aren't simultaneous.

Comment: Almost everything is *possible* in ruby it just depends on how hard you want to work for it. (Most of the time it is not worth the effort)

Comment: Thanks to all those commented. I already know that It can be do using map/ collect. I just wanted to know is it possible or not. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Can't do that with a single pass and the shorthand. Either do two passes

```
objects_array.collect(&:errors).collect(&:full_messages)
```

or use the full form.

```
objects_array.collect{ |obj| obj.errors.full_messages }
```

Comment: although it will work but unnecessary intermediate array and 2 loops.. :)

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon: yes, that's what I say :)

Answer (score 2):

> Can It possible?

No, it is just a shorthand method, use block instead..

```
objects_array.collect { |obl| obj.errors.full_messages }
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible if you redefine `Symbol#method_missing` to store the method chain, and also redefine `Symbol#to_proc` to expand into a proc using the stored method chain. But I am pretty sure that it would introduce complexity more than it helps, and cause some severe problems. It is not worth doing.

Comment: And it would only work for undefined methods, i.e. `[1, 10, 100].map(&:to_s.length)` would raise a `TypeError` instead of returning `[1, 2, 3]` because `Symbol` responds to `length`.

Comment: @Stefan yes, more sophisticated combination of `undef_method` and marshaling of calls to `method_missing` “original methods” should take place here.

Comment: @Stefan <del>OTOH `Symbol#to_proc` might return an extended `Proc` descendant, that returns a proc wrapped with `TypeError` rescuer, that in turn would delegate calls to where they belong.</del> That won’t work.

Comment: @mudasobwa we are certainly heading in the right direction ;-) What about patching Ruby's parser?

Comment: @Stefan Patching Ruby’s parser is silly, what about introducing a Ruby Preprocessor, that will allow macros?

Comment: @mudasobwa instead why not add `String#to_proc` the likes of `def to_proc; self.split('.').inject(->(obj) {obj}) {|memo,meth| Proc.new {|*args| memo.call(args.shift).__send__(meth,*args)}}; end`. Then we can call as `objects_array.collect(&"errors.full_messages")`

Comment: @engineersmnky this is a green route :)

Comment: @mudasobwa how about this one instead `Symbol#proc_chain` e.g. `def proc_chain(args); args.inject(self.to_proc) { |chain,meth| meth,*passable_args = [meth].flatten; Proc.new {|obj| chain.call(obj).__send__(meth,*passable_args)}};end` called like `[1,2,3,4,5].map(&:itself.proc_chain([:to_s,2],[:to_i,10])) #=> [1, 10, 11, 100, 101]`

Comment: @engineersmnky If I could bounty-reward the comment, I definitely would. Thanks, it made my day :)

Comment: @mudasobwa I posted it [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44978446/1978251) and allowed block passing too.