# Is there any way to use more than one attribute/method with ampersand colon operator in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

It would be something like this: Given an array of `foo` objects with an attribute `bar` which also has an attribute called `baz`:

```
foos.each(&:bar.baz)
```

I can easily get all `bar`s with `foos.each(&:bar)`, but the `baz` attribute (or however many others could it be) I cannot, as it gives me the error:
`TypeError: wrong argument type String (expected Proc)`

Comment: I assumed, as per your example, that you wanted to use a single ampersand operator, but you awarded the greenie to an answer that does the conventional thing, chaining two calculations that each make use of an ampersand operator. Please clarify.

Comment: No, I didn't want a single ampersand, just a way to chain the calls of `bar` and `baz`. But you answer work for me, as the accepted one. thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`.map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-map):

```
foos.map(&:bar).each(&:baz)
```

This will turn your array of `foo` items into an array of `bar` items, allowing you to call `.each` on that instead.

Comment: This does not answer the question; it's a work-around.

Comment: @CarySwoveland The question was **"Is there any way to use more than one attribute/method with ampersand colon operator in Ruby?"** and this answer shows how you do that.

Comment: I've asked the OP for clarification. btw, why do you assume that `foos.map(&:bar).each(&:baz)` is wanted, rather than `foos.each(&:bar).map(&:baz)` or `foos.each(&:bar).each(&:baz)`? I realize `each` returns its receiver but it can also have side effects.

Answer (score 3):

[Array#each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-each) returns its receiver, so it may not be the best example of what you are looking for. Suppose we have

```
arr = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]
```

and want

```
arr.map(&:first).map(&:upcase)
  #=> ["A", "C"]
```

To use a single ampersand one could write

```
arr.map(&Proc.new { |e| e.first.upcase })
  #=> ["A", "C"]
```

`&` converts the proc to a block, causing

```
arr.map { |e| e.first.upcase }
```

to be executed.

Comment: I am very happy to have you here ! Thanks for sharing your knowledge.

Comment: Additionally we can go with all the fun everyone had [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34579603/chaining-to-proc-on-symbol) or the insanity of [`J-uby`](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby)

Comment: It is another interesting way to do what I wanted. Besides that, yours and Sergio  explanation made me understand better the `&` operator. As the GoBusto answer also resolve my question I will keep it. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible with ampersand colon operator

No. Primarily because there's no such thing as "ampersand colon operator". This

```
foos.each(&:bar)
```

is a shorter way of writing this

```
sym = :bar
foos.each(&sym)
```

Also see other answers for alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

The best option is to just use the regular block syntax:

```
foos.each { |foo| foo.bar.baz }
```

If you still want to use the `&:sym` type of syntax, for example because the method names are dynamic, you can check out the [Xf](https://github.com/baweaver/xf) gem. It enables you to do:

```
foos.each(&Xf.pipe(:bar, :baz))
```

You can replicate the functionality without including the gem simply by borrowing the [`pipe`](https://github.com/baweaver/xf/blob/master/lib/xf/public_api.rb#L20-L26) method:

```
def pipe(*fns)
  Proc.new do |target|
    new_value = target
    fns.each { |fn| new_value = fn.to_proc.call(new_value) }
    new_value
  end
end

require 'ostruct'
# openstruct used to emulate objects that would respond to .foo.bar
foos = []
foos << OpenStruct.new(foo: OpenStruct.new(bar: 'hello'))
foos << OpenStruct.new(foo: OpenStruct.new(bar: 'world'))
foos.each(&pipe(:foo, :bar))
```

Comment: Why `map` rather than `each`? Based on the information given in the question can we conclude which is correct?

Comment: No reason, changed to each.